# What is advantage of setMaxConcurrentOperationCount =1

Tags: ios

I am reading `NSOperationQueue` blogs and documents.

We can set number of concurrent operation in `NSOperationQueue` by `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount` attribute.

My doubt is If I am  using `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount =1` then, it mean my queue can execute only single task at a time. Then what is meaning of concurrency, it become single thread execution.

Please tell me, If I am interpreting wrong meaning.

Comment: Instead of setting maxConcurrentOperationCount=1. You could make an operation dependent on the completion of another operation which would essentially have the same effect. E.g. A depends on B, but make sure B doesn't depend on A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it will only execute one task at a time. There are cases, where it makes sense to set it one at a time. For example, download photos and applying filters to them. From your point of view, it's preferable to download one at a time, apply the filter and store it/show it. As Jonathan added on the comment:

> Instead of setting maxConcurrentOperationCount=1. You could make an
>   operation dependent on the completion of another operation which would
>   essentially have the same effect. E.g. A depends on B, but make sure B
>   doesn't depend on A.

The `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount =1` is nice for this kind of stuff:

```
[myOperationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
for (NSOperation *operation in myArrayOfOperations )
{
   [myOperationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

So you add new operations on a loop, but they will run in a serial queue. Still, from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/addOperation%3a):

> An operation queue executes its queued operation objects based on
>   their priority and readiness. If all of the queued operation objects
>   have the same priority and are ready to execute when they are put in
>   the queue—that is, their isReady method returns YES—they are executed
>   in the order in which they were submitted to the queue. For a queue
>   whose maximum number of concurrent operations is set to 1, this
>   equates to a serial queue. However, you should never rely on the
>   serial execution of operation objects. Changes in the readiness of an
>   operation can change the resulting execution order.

Comment: Good point. I think adding dependencies and setting the priority would be a better option though since you could still have concurrency and run multiple operations which are dependent on each other. Such as the example you provided.

Comment: Thanks guys..It really help me to understand the meaning of setting the operation count :)

Comment: V.J. You need to accept answers. You're not using this site properly. None of your questions have accepted answers.

Answer (score 0):

mean that the operations in queue are executed one by one, when one finish another one can start, so chosing 1 your queue is a SERIAL queue

Answer (score 0):

Setting maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1 effectively changes an NSOperation queue to a serial queue, so you avoid concurrency problems at the cost of executing one task at a time only.

HOWEVER you can have as many NSOperationQueues as you like. And a dozen NSOperationQueues with maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1 can all run tasks simultaneously, using a dozen cores if you have them. The only restriction is that only one task can run in each queue.